# Starting activity using implicit intent for a Location result

Tags: android, android-intent, implicit

is there an already implemented implicit intent to start an activity that would return the user current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such intents. But you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get user location. 
Here's a good explanation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html